# How to debug exe that invoked by another in vs2005

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2005

VS2005  c++

I have a sln that contain 2 exe   and  several dll
A.exe invoke B.exe  than   B.exe invoke other dll

I wanna insert break point in codes of B.exe and  dll
but if I set A.exe the startup project,  breakpoint in B and dll is invalid

if I set B.exe the startup project, than only B.exe runing, but A.exe is necessary for me
because lot of thing must be done by A

if set Both A  and  B  the startup project, it's avalible to debug B, but you know
when A runing ,it will invoke another B, so  2 B.exe run at sametime ,that's not what i want

so ,any one could help me, i was really boring for this for a long time,

any suggestion is  appritate  thanks

Comment: Visual Studio 2005 supports attaching to multiple running processes. Debug/Attach To Process... Just debug A, let it launch B, and attach to it.

Comment: thanks dude ,I made a sample solution include a shell.exe ,a dllcall.exe  and a  dlltest.dll, it works with your mathod,but in my orignal solution which is a huge solution and made by QT ,it dosen't work, i don't know why , because of QT?

Comment: Can't answer that one. I never use it. It *should* work, so that seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug as many Bs as you want - just launch enough Visual Studio 2005 instances, open your project in each instance of MSVC 2005, choose Debug -> "Attach to Proces" and select required instance of B process.

Comment: thanks dude too, the same "attach to process" mathod ,but still can't work in my orignal solution which I said above.

Comment: And i feel so interesting that how can vs know where the sourecode of a process is, most of process just a  precees or a application, just for use ,not for coding

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Image File Execution Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\B.exe]
"Debugger"="vsjitdebugger.exe"
```

And you may have to run this command before to get it working in the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

```
vsjitdebugger.exe /regserver
```

Then when the B.exe get executed, there should be a pop-up window ask you to debug it.

In your source code, you can also insert [DebugBreak()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to break the debugger.

Comment: I'm sorry that i still can't make sense about what you said, i need little more time to understand and try it, but still thank you a lot

Comment: I learned the article of yours, it seems like the MS offical solution,very nice ,although i hadn't really try it  because of I have no authority to change my regedit ,you know, IT statagy